# Starting tomcat 7 throws two exceptions, End event and web.xml parsing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, web.xml

When I attempt to run my project on Tomcat I get these exceptions.

```
Apr 21, 2014 4:20:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1809)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1464)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Apr 21, 2014 4:20:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.53/libexec/conf/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.53/libexec/conf/web.xml; lineNumber: 105; columnNumber: 15; Error at (105, 15) : org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2711)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1066)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1809)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1464)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
    ... 26 more
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>search.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Stroop1</groupId>
  <artifactId>Stroop1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.53</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.sven-jacobs</groupId>
        <artifactId>loremipsum</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.53</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Your installation is broken.  Download a new Tomcat and use it from your home folder.

Comment: I just did that, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be a runtime conflict between classes in one of the *org.apache.tomcat* libraries pulled in by your *pom.xml* and classes included in the Tomcat installation itself.

There is likely to be a version difference between *7.0.53*, which your project depends on (and include in the WAR file), and the Tomcat installation you're deploying to, which could cause conflicting classes to reside in the *org.apache.catalina* namespace during runtime.

Try adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to the *org.apache.tomcat* dependencies in your *pom.xml* to exclude them from the WAR file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.53</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.53</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```